# Footer view as RelativeLaout

Tags: android, layout

I have a RelativeLayout which `includes` following RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/day_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="day"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/month_button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="month"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/week_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/day_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/month_button1"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This layout will be shown as a footer for the page.
As you see the `maxLines` for EditText is 5. When the line size is more than 2 in EditText, buttons around it start to move a bit up.
I want buttons stick to the end of page and do not move. Any solution?

I tried adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for buttons but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds to be as a bug in the UI framework, but there's usually work around to achieve the same visual effect.

For example, replacing this `RelativeLayout` you show in the XML to a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` should give the same visual effect.

pseudo code

```
<LinearLayout horizontal>
   <Button wrap_content layout_gravity=bottom/>
   <EditText width=0dp weight=1/> // makes EditText fill remaining space
   <Button wrap_content layout_gravity=bottom/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As soon as Edit text line are more than 1, buttons move up.

Comment: ops, my bad, I added two missing parameters on my pseudo code, does it solve?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try to add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` **for all child elements**.</strike>

It works at least in Android Studio.

**UPDATED**

Add `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/week_button"` for both buttons.

[image]

Comment: That's what I exactly did. The footer layout took the whole page. Note that the footer layout is in another Relative Layout.